# Missing data in Python

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas, bigdata

I'm trying to import a JSON file into Python to do some data analysis. Each JSON object has a lot of different variables in it (about 7-10). Some objects have certain variables, while other objects don't. I am interested in specifically five variables from each json line. However, some objects have missing data. How do I make it so that the program will put a None for every missing data?

```
import json
data = []
keys = ["hostid","time", "userid","link", "title"]
m = len(keys)

with open('test.json') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        dataline = json.loads(line)
        row = []
        for i in xrange(m):
            row.append(dataline[keys[i]])
        data.append(row)
json_data.close()

data = np.array(data)
```

Here are some sample JSON objects. As you can see the first object has all five variables that I want, but the second object does not have data for the "title" variable.

```
{
"title": "Monster Man", 
"link": "http://monsters4ever.com/tagged/rosemary%27s%20baby%20(1968)",
"userid": 130290, 
"field5": "lezmer Brunch at City Winery? Who Knew? -- Grub Street Chicago\"", 
"hostid": "3969937ab0a3e2db8690c482564006a7", 
"time": 376541
}

{
"link": "http://www.sfgate.com/world/article/WORLD-News-of-the-Day-From-Across-the-Globe-4120318.php", 
"userid": 227954, "field5": "ries &laquo; SHEfinds\"", 
"hostid": "6096407936827c96fa0833f26ab33b76", 
"time": 376541
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Going to be hard to help you without any knowledge of the structure of the JSON.

Comment: Fill with none and overwrite with keys found.

Comment: @Floris I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @PhillipCloud Added the info into my post!

Comment: `json_data.close()` is unnecessary since you opened the file using a context manager (`with` statement)

Comment: Generally speaking, `for i in xrange(len(thing)): ... thing[i]` should be replaced with `for item in thing: ... item`.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use try.  I'd also just iterate through the keys list.

```
with open('test.json') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        dataline = json.loads(line)
        row = []
        for i in keys:#iterate through keys
            try:
                row.append(dataline[i])
            except:
                pass
        data.append(row)
json_data.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than filling in the missing data,  when you try to retrieve the data from the object, instead of the usual:  `x['field']`, try `x.get('field')`.

e.g.:

```
with open('test.json') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        dataline = json.loads(line)
        row = []
        for key in keys:
            row.append(dataline.get(key))

        # better is:
        # row = [dataline.get(key) for key in keys]

        data.append(row)
```

This works because `dict.get` returns `None` if the key isn't found in the dictionary.

---

If you really don't want to do that, and you know the fields that you want, you can use `dict.setdefault` to put `None` in there:

```
for field in fields_you_care_about:
    obj.setdefault(field, None)
```

Comment: Do you mean instead of `row.append(dataline[keys[i]])` use `row.append(dataline[keys.get(i)])`?

Comment: @user3287712 -- updated with a modified version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `try`, since it should throw an exception when you attempt to call a key that doesn't exist:

```
import json
data = []
keys = ["hostid","time", "userid","link", "title"]
m = len(keys)

with open('test.json') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        dataline = json.loads(line)
        row = []
        for i in xrange(m):
            try:
                row.append(dataline[keys[i]])
            except Exception:
                row.append(None)
        data.append(row)
json_data.close()

data = np.array(data)
```